# i have two gateways for destination for single route

Tags: routing, ethernet, redundancy

i have two gateways for single route 
Ex.

```
destination 172.20.100.4  gateways 10.22.0.9 and 10.192.168.18
```

I want to add both routes in my route add if one is fail traffic goes automatically from other source.

```
route add 172.20.100.4 mask 255.255.255.255 10.22.0.9 
route add 172.20.100.4 mask 255.255.255.255 10.192.168.18
```

what metric do I install for both routes and both IP addresses for single Ethernet..

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you need some kinda mechanism to track the feasibility status of a route.
So, you assign higher metric to the backup route, and when the tracking mechanism sense that the route is not active, it will switch to the backup route.

In Cisco IOS, this could be achieved by SLA and Track.
In JunOS, you have to use IP Monitoring and RPM.

Answer (score 0):

If your are having two route for different gateways for same destination . Then one route will act as active and another one as passive  this can be accomplished by adding AD value higher than one ..

`route add 172.20.100.4 mask 255.255.255.255 10.22.0.9 1`

`route add 172.20.100.4 mask 255.255.255.255 10.192.168.18 2`